# Optimize PHP+CURL connection times

Tags: php, curl, nginx

I have PHP scripts doing CURL POST requests to distant Nginx servers via HTTPS (several times per second).

My issue is that each request needs 3 round-trips (TCP connection + SSL handshake) before the transfer can start, which significantly slows down the process.

Is there a way to do reduce this, for instance with some sort of "Keep-Alive" to avoid renegotiating TCP / SSL for each request?

Thank you!

Comment: `http 1.1` is keep-alived by default, you may send several requests through the same connection, just don't close it explicitly.

Comment: How do you maintain a connection between different scripts? Each scripts does 1 request and then stops

Comment: Presumably you cannot, it's nothing in the question that clarifies that. So I assumed a script runs multiple requests at once. In case of independent scripts the only solution is to move a server that runs scripts closer to the destination server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to keep a connection alive between two different PHP execution as the PHP script "die" at the end (thus closing any open socket), the only way to do what you want to achieve would be to have a background PHP script that never stops, takes care of fetching the data and put them into a database or a file that you will be able to easily and rapidly query later.

On another topic making multiple HTTPS request per second is maybe not the most efficient way to do it, if you have the hand on the server you query you might want to use WebSockets, that would allow you to make multiple queries per second without any major performance issue

I hope this answered you question, have a good day